# How can I remove a newline character or empty string from a list when using readline() with Python?

Tags: python, string, newline

I'd like to know how I can remove the newline character (or if the strip method is used, how to remove the remaining empty string) from a list. Here's the code I have so far:

```
pixel_start = 0
pixel_width = 25
pixel_height = 6
layer_dimension = pixel_width * pixel_height
pixel_end = layer_dimension
layers = []


def get_layer():
    return layer_list[pixel_start:pixel_end]


def increment_layer(pixel_start, pixel_end):
    pixel_start += layer_dimension
    pixel_end += layer_dimension
    return pixel_start, pixel_end


with open('pixel_layers.txt') as layer_file:
    layer_list = layer_file.readline().strip()

while len(layers) <= (len(layer_list) / layer_dimension):
    layers.append(get_layer())
    pixel_start, pixel_end = increment_layer(pixel_start, pixel_end)

layers = layers[:-1]
```

The file only contains a single line of 1500 characters plus a newline. The rest of the code breaks that list up into a list of 100 items, each of those lists being 150 characters. However, it actually ends up being 101 items, because even with the strip method, it leaves an empty string as the 101st item in the list.

How can I avoid this? I don't want either the newline or the empty string in the final list. For now I have that last line in there to remove it, but that's ugly and not at all the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an abbreviated (say, 300 or so characters, so just the first two items) version of the input so that we can experiment on our own with this? The problem isn't immediately apparent to me.

Comment: In your example `len(layer_list) / layer_dimension` is close to `10`, so your `len(layers)` can't be more than 10

Comment: I'm not sure how to attach a file, but here is the first 300 values:

221002222122020222021022222022222222222222222222221222222022220222112022220222022020222202222222220222222222221222212222222222222222222222222222022222220202222122121222022122222122222222222222222222222222222022221222102022221222122220222202222222220222222222222222202222222222222222222222222222222222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to remove the extra last empty element from the list 'layers'. This can be solved if you remove the '=' sign from the while loop.

```
while len(layers) < (len(layer_list) / layer_dimension):
    layers.append(get_layer())
    pixel_start, pixel_end = increment_layer(pixel_start, pixel_end)

print(layers)
```

This is because, when you run the while loop it appends an empty string to the list when it does not find any characters which is when the counter = 10.

Answer (score 0):

To remove trailing newlines from string you should use `layer_file.readline().rstrip('\n')`. But if your file is big and you know the index of its first `'\n'` character you can simplify it a bit:

```
from itertools import repeat
from math import ceil

pixel_width = 25
pixel_height = 6
layer_dimension = pixel_width * pixel_height
layer_file_length = 1501
layers_max_size =  ceil(layer_file_length / layer_dimension)

with open('pixel_layers.txt', 'tr') as layer_file:
    layers = list(map(layer_file.read, repeat(layer_dimension, layers_max_size)))
    if last_chunk := layers.pop().rstrip('\n'):
        layers.append(last_chunk)

assert len(layers) == 10
```